# How to create a word grouping report using R language and .Net?

Tags: r, c#-4.0, statistics

I would like to create a simple application in C# that takes in a group of words, then returns all groupings of those individual words from a data set.

For example, given car and bike, return a list of groups/combinations of words (with the number of combinations found) from a data set.

To further clarify - given a category named "car", I would like to see a list of word groupings with the word "car".  This category could also be several words rather than just one.

With a sample data set of:

CAR:

- Another car for sale
- Blue car on the horizon
- For Sale - used car
- this car is painted blue

should return

```
car : for sale : 2
car : blue : 2
```

I'd like to set a threshold, say 20 or greater, so if there are over 20 instances of the word(s) with car, then display them - `category`, `words`, `count`, where only `category` is known; `words` and `count` is determined by the algorithm.

The data set is in a SQL Server 2008 table, and I was hoping to use something like a .Net implementation of R to accomplish this.

I am guessing that the best way to accomplish this may be with the R programming language, and am only now looking at R.Net.

I would prefer to do this with .Net, as that is what I am most familiar with, but open to suggestions.

Can someone with some experience with this lead me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a little more your result here?  `car : for sale : 2`?surely I miss something here.

Comment: Can you give a 5 line example dataframe of what you're after? Also, is it essential that you use .NET? There are many ways of producing documents from R, in particular `knitr`.

Comment: I added to the description - hopefully that is better understood and you can remove the -1's.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question consists of 4 parts:

1. Getting data from SQL Server 2008
2. Extracting substrings from a set of strings
3. Setting a threshold for when to accept that number
4. Producing some document or other output (?) containing this.

For 1, I think that's a different question (see the `RODBC` package), but I won't be dealing with that here as that's not the main part of your question. You've left 4. a little vague and I think that's also peripheral to the meat of your question.

Part 2 can be easily dealt with using regular expressions:

```
countstring <- function(string, pattern){
  stringcount <- sum(grepl(pattern, string, ignore.case=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE)
  paste(deparse(substitute(string)), pattern, stringcount, sep=" : ")
}
```

This function basically gets a vector of strings and a pattern to search for. It finds which of them match and gets the sum of the number that do (ie the count). It then prints out these together in one string. For example:

```
car <- c("Another car for sale", "Blue car on the horizon", "For Sale - used car", "this car is painted blue")
countstring(car, "blue")
## [1] "car : blue : 2"
```

Part 3 requires a small change to the function

```
countstring <- function(string, pattern, threshold=20){
  stringcount <- sum(grepl(pattern, string, ignore.case=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE)

  if(stringcount >= threshold){
    paste(deparse(substitute(string)), pattern, stringcount, sep=" : ")
  }

}
```

Comment: So I still have -2 up there hey?   Thank you for the insight, and you are correct in the breakdown.  I can extract the data from SQL server just fine and store this in a collection for the function/algo to access.  Maybe what I should have clarified is that I won't know the pattern, only the string (referring to your function).  Your function assumes we know what the pattern is to find, however that's part of the problem - finding those patterns that occur in greater numbers.  I may need to further clarify... let me know.

Comment: The -2 is likely a combination of the fact you have asked so many questions in one go and the vagueness of those questions. A good SO question is minimal, reproducible and contains some code containing some of your efforts. This gives us some guidelines for answering your question as well as making it easy to answer. How can you not know the pattern? You have to know it at some point. When you do, use it as input.

Comment: thanks.  Do you have a better idea about what I'm trying to create - where the pattern is not known, or does this need further explaining?

Comment: @ElHaix I'm not sure at all what you're trying to create, but it sounds like you're new to R. I think you might want to break your problem down first, do some research on those parts and come back when you're stuck. I think it might be good to see what resources are out there and practise going through documentation. That should solidify your understanding and make you better able to ask clear questions.